# How to auto approve photo after post it on facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I build a app facebook with c# sdk, i posted a photo and then i go to album but that photo need user approve to add into album. How i can do that user dont need click approve, photo is still added into the album.